# Prove that a simple graph with $2$ vertices without triangles inside has at most $n^2$ lines.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

A triangle in a graph is a subset of the node set $\{a, b, c\} \subseteq V (G)$ such that $\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\} \in E (G).$ Prove with induction for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that a graph without a triangle with $2n$ nodes has at most $n^2$ edges.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.   Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial part of the proof is to choose two vertices $u,v$ say, which are connected.
Then there are at most $2n-2$ edges from these points to other points (they cannot both be joined to the same point).

Then by induction the number of edges is at most $1+(2n-2)+(n-1)^2=n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i do not understand your induction step. Where did the 1 and the (n-1)^2 come from ?

Comment: The "1" is the edge between u and v. Then there are at most  $(n-1)^2$ edges between the $2(n-1)$ edges ( by the inductive hypothesis).